# Lower bounds on the matching number of maximal planar graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, planar-graphs, matching-theory

I have read the following article in which the authors briefly prove that the lower bound on the matching number of a maximal planar graph is $\frac{n+8}{3}$.

- Biedl, T., & Wittnebel, J. (2023). Large Matchings in Maximal 1-planar graphs. arXiv preprint arXiv:2301.01394.

I didn't understand one of the steps in the proof below.

[image]

I can only get

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{comp}(G\setminus S)-|S|&=\sum_df_d^\odot-|S|\\
&=\sum_df_d^\odot-\big(\frac{\sum_d(d-2)f_d+4}{2}\big)\\
&=\sum_df_d^\odot-\big(\frac{\sum_d(d-2)f_d}{2}\big)-2.
\end{align}
$$

Why did the authors get $\operatorname{comp}(G\setminus S)-|S|\le \frac{1}{2}f^\odot_3-2$?

Thank you for the response from Misha Lavrov. I think it is necessary to clarify some concepts. I will first excerpt some necessary definitions from the article as follows.

**Eidts:**
The *face-boundary* is the boundary of F, viewed
as a collection of circuits in the graph (some of those circuits may consist of just one vertex,
or of a single edge visited twice).

Define the *degree* $\deg(F)$ of $F$ to be $m_F+2 \operatorname{comp}(F)-2$, where $m_F$ is number of edge-incidences
in the face-boundary (repeatedly visited edges count twice).

Therefore, for a face bounded by an isolated vertex, its degree  is $0+2\times 1-2=0$.  For a face bounded by an  edge, its degree is $2+2\times 1-2=2$. For a face bounded by two isolated vertices, its degree is $0+2\times 2-2=2$.

[image: ![enter image description here]

For example,  considering the following maximal planar graph with 16 vertices. If we choose $S=\{v\}$, then we  $f_0^\odot$ will appear in $\Gamma (S)$. Now $\operatorname{comp}(G\setminus S)-|S|=1-1=0>0-2$ (since $f_3^\odot =0$).

[image: ![enter image description here]

Similarly, if we choose $S=\{u,v\}$, then $f_2^\odot$ will appear in $\Gamma (S)$.Now $\operatorname{comp}(G\setminus S)-|S|=1-2=-1>0-2$ (since $f_3^\odot =0$).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first source of an inequality rather than an equation comes from applying $f_d^\odot \le f_d$ to every term of the second sum:
$$
   \operatorname{comp}(G \setminus S) - |S| \le \sum_d f_d^\odot - \frac{\sum_d (d-2) f_d^\odot}{2} - 2.
$$
We can now simplify this to
$$
   \operatorname{comp}(G \setminus S) - |S| \le \sum_d (2 - \tfrac d2)f_d^\odot - 2.
$$

For $d \ge 4$, the coefficient on $f_d^\odot$ is non-positive, and we can drop all those terms in the inequality. Degree-$1$ faces are impossible, and if degree-$0$ and degree-$2$ faces do not exist, then $\frac12 f_3^\odot$ is the only term left; this gives us the desired
$$
   \operatorname{comp}(G \setminus S) - |S| \le \frac12 f_3^\odot - 2.
$$
As pointed out in the question, the inequality is false if there is a degree-$2$ face, so we do have to worry about $f_0^\odot$ and $f_2^\odot$ terms. However, such faces are very limited.

[The paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.01394) defines the degree of a face $F$ to be $m_F + 2 \text{comp}(F)-2$, where $m_F$ is the usual face length (counting edges double if $F$ is on both sides of the edge) and $\text{comp}(F)$ is the number of components of $F$. Therefore:

- A degree-$0$ face can only exist if $S$ is a *single* isolated vertex.
- A degree-$2$ face can only exist if $S$ is either two isolated vertices, or two adjacent vertices.

In each of these cases, $\operatorname{comp}(G \setminus S) - |S|$ is either $0$, $-1$, or $-2$. In the end, we want to show that $\operatorname{comp}(G \setminus S) - |S| \le \frac{n-8}{3}$, which holds in all cases where degree-$0$ or degree-$2$ faces appear.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. It is indeed true that $f_d^\odot\le f_d$ . However, according to the definition of degree across a face in the article and the selection of $S$ (which can be an isolated vertex or an edge), the degree of the face of $\Gamma(S)$ does not necessarily start from 3. Please refer to the section I added for details.

Comment: Please explain, then, what a face of degree 1 looks like.

Comment: Hold on, I am currently making detailed edits.

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov Could you please take a look at my new edits? If there are any misunderstandings, please don't hesitate to let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited to address the degree-$0$ and degree-$2$ faces.

Comment: Indeed, the occurrence of these situations does not affect the final outcome. Thank you very much.